# yii multi schema postgresql, data inserted but return error sequence not exist

Tags: yii, postgresql-9.1

i have 2 schema on postgresql egg: public,items.  in public schema all CRUD ok  but when i'm try to insert on items schema there is a problem.
the problem is, data inserted but the yii framework return error 'items.table1_id_seq doesn't exist'.
when i'm check to the database the squence is exist.
how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

check the tableName function into protected/models/table.php
The table must be nameSchema.table

```
public function tableName()
{
    return 'items.nameOfTable';
}
```